# StatusBarHidden not working

Tags: iphone

Stumped on this one.  I am using a section of code posted here to rotate a view into landscape.  Rotate, sizing and animations are working great, but when the view rotates, the status bar hangs around as a thin gray strip, which is the same size as the hidden status bar.

Here is the code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];         
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {      
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates on this? Seems like iOS 7 has a different approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957926/1049134

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `wantsFullScreenLayout = YES` on your view controller?

Comment: Gave it a shot, no effect.  Tried it just after I alloc'd the controller and in the load and willdisplay.

Answer (score 0):

iOS7: I added the following code to the **Info.plist** to get rid of the status bar permanently. Found it in another stackexchange question.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```