# Setting UIApplication statusBarHidden to YES does not work in iOS 7

Tags: uiviewcontroller, statusbar, ios7, uiapplication

I've been using

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

to hide the status bar when users enter specific UIViewControllers in iOS 6 and it worked great. In iOS 7 however it still shows a translucent overlay.

Answer (score 5):

EDITED:::

that is new updated answer :
Do in plist file

"View controller-based status bar appearance"  to NO 
and write code

```
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

in appdelegate

Comment: Just adding the final `prefersStatusBarHidden` method was all I needed for iOS 7 while keeping `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;` in `viewWillAppear:` kept working in iOS 6 without breaking iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES in my app's Info.plist.

Comment: setting "View controller-based status bar appearance" in the Info.plist worked for me

Comment: My bad; I misread your original question to mean that you wanted it hidden all the time.