# How to make the system bar disappear?

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm developing an application for iOS 7.

I want to make the system bar (see the following screenshot) disappear like Facebook's Paper does on it's main screen.

[image: System bar]

I know how to change the bar's background color with a transition but not how make the bar completely disappear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897983/setting-uiapplication-statusbarhidden-to-yes-does-not-work-in-ios-7/18957926#18957926

Answer (score 0):

You can set these values

In app Delegate :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
      return YES;
}
```

in viewWillAppear :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

add "View controller-based status bar appearance = NO" in your .plist file.

and also add Status bar is initially hidden = YES

that works for me.